# how to display elements of ArrayList without the braces

Tags: java, arraylist

I wrote the following code, when I run it it displays the answer in the form [#, #, #, #]. I want it to display it as # # # # (without the braces and commas) and without using system.out.print. somehow, I want to store the result in one variable and just invoke that variable.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class trial 

{

static Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);   

public static ArrayList<Integer> primeFactors(long number) 

{

        long n = number;
        ArrayList<Integer> factors = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        for (int i = 2; i <= n; i++) 
        {
            while (n % i == 0) 
            {
                factors.add(i);
                n /= i;
            }
        }

        return factors;

}
public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    System.out.println("Enter phone number to be factored");
    long input = keyboard.nextLong();

    System.out.println(primeFactors(input));
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at what it is returning https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/AbstractCollection.html#toString()

Change it to

```
System.out.println(primeFactors(input)
          .toString().replace("[", "").replace("]", "").replace(",", " ");
```

or just iterate through and print the values

Comment: as per my knowledge, it's not a recommended way

Answer (score 0):

You can change the return type in to String on primeFactors method. Then loop ArrayList and add content in to String as show below.

```
package src.main;

import java.util.Scanner;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class sampleMain

{

static Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

public static String primeFactors(long number)

{

    long n = number;
    ArrayList<Integer> factors = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    for (int i = 2; i <= n; i++) {
        while (n % i == 0) {
            factors.add(i);
            n /= i;
        }
    }
    StringBuffer output = new StringBuffer();
    for (Integer integer : factors) {
        if( output.length()==0 ){
            output.append(integer.toString());
        }else{
            output.append(", "+integer.toString());
        }
    }
    return output.toString();

}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("Enter phone number to be factored");
    long input = keyboard.nextLong();

    System.out.println(primeFactors(input));
}
}
```

**Updated** the answer with StringBuffer based on comment

Comment: If doing this way, better to use a StringBuilder

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at Java8 `Collectors.joining` and `String.join` methods, you can iterate over list and print it as you needed

using `Collectors.joining`

```
List<String> strs = Arrays.asList("a", "b", "c", "d", "e");
String str = strs.stream().collect(Collectors.joining(" ")));
```

or even simply

```
String s = String.join(" ", primeFactors);
```

or using `StringBuilder`

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
for (E e : primeFactors) {
    sb.append(e).append(" ");
}
String ret = sb.toString().trim();
```

output

```
a b c d e
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to iterate the values in your `ArrayList` and append it to a StringBuilder. Like this:

```
    StringBuilder oneStringValue = new StringBuilder();
    for(Integer tempNum : primeFactors(input)) {
        oneStringValue.append(tempNum.toString());
    }
    System.out.println(oneStringValue.toString());
```

That should work.

For added Information, I used `StringBuilder` to append strings because it's `mutable`, rather than `String` that is `immutable`.

Answer (score 0):

Simply use for each loop:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter phone number to be factored");
    long input = keyboard.nextLong();
    ArrayList<Integer> arr = primeFactors(input);
    for(int a:arr){
        System.out.print(a+" ");
    }
    keyboard.close();
}
```